# Change bookmark action Named destination to page number

Tags: java, itext

I need to change bookmark actions Properties **Named destination** to **Page number** of an existing pdf file, using `iText` java code

[image]

```
   public void BookmarkZoomLevelChange(List<HashMap<String, Object>> list,
        PdfReader reader) {
    for (HashMap<String, Object> entry : list) {

        for (String key : entry.keySet()) {
            // System.out.println(key);
            if ("Kids".equals(key)) {
                Object o = entry.get(key);

                BookmarkZoomLevelChange((List<HashMap<String, Object>>) o,
                        reader);
            } else if ("Page".equals(key)) {
                String dest = (String) entry.get(key);
                // System.out.println(dest);
                if (dest.contains("FitR")) {

                    String cord[] = dest.substring(dest.indexOf("R"))
                            .split(" ");
                    entry.put("Page", dest.replaceAll("FitR", "XYZ "
                            + cord[1] + " " + cord[4] + " 0"));
                } else if (dest.contains("XYZ")) {
                    String cord[] = dest.substring(dest.indexOf("XYZ"))
                            .split(" ");
                    entry.put("Page", dest.replaceAll("XYZ", "XYZ "
                            + cord[1] + " " + cord[2] + " 0"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

using above code i did not get  `("Page".equals(key))`. So, how to convert Named destination to Page Number?

Comment: Which version of iText? iText 5 or iText 7?

Comment: @ Bruno iText 5

Comment: Ok. So... what have you tried yet, where did you run into trouble?

Comment: @mkl I have updated the question with sample code

Comment: OK, but you are trying to do something the hard way, while the "iText in Action" book shows how to do it the easy way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the API documentation for the version you are using, more specifically at the methods available in the `PdfReader` class. You'll find the [`consolidateNamedDestinations()`](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html#consolidateNamedDestinations--) method that is described as follows:

> Replaces all the local named links with the actual destinations.

You have named destinations. You don't like this. You want the named destinations to be replaced by explicit destinations that point to a specific location on a specific page. That's exactly what the `consolidateNamedDestinations()` method is about.

Try this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
reader.consolidateNamedDestinations();
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
stamper.close();
```

Normally, there should be no links to named destinations in the `dest` PDF anymore.

Comment: @ Bruno Thank you for your answer what I exactly want

Comment: @ Bruno  I have use reader.consolidateNamedDestinations(); for to change Named destination to Page number of an existing pdf file it's working fine and also change the ZoomLevel=Inherit Zoom of Bookmark what exactly I want, but internal link of pdf pages ZoomLevel=Custom set after but i need to set ZoomLevel=Inherit Zoom for all interlink use in pdf pages,

Comment: @ Bruno i have post new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47344107/change-the-zoom-level-of-all-links-of-an-existing-pdf-file-using-itext5